# Can I fetch JSON in html table with positive value only

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch-api

I want to fetch JSON API in html table only with value above 10.

Here's my code and my JavaScript. I don't want JSON to fetch negative and value with 0 only positive value; is there anyway to short this out?

```
<html>
    <body>
<div class="container">
    
    <table class="table table-bordered" style="white-space:nowrap;"
     id="table1">
        <thead class="table-dark" style="white-space:nowrap;"
        >
            <tr class="tr" style="white-space:nowrap;"
            >
                <th>OI</th>
                <th>OI Change</th>
                <th>Volume</th>
                <th>Change LTP</th>
                <th>LTP</th>
                <th>Strike Price</th>
                <th>LTP</th>
                <th>Volome</th>
                <th>Change LTP</th>
                <th>OI Change</th>
                <th>OI</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="datapcr">
        
        <tbody>
      </table>
</div>
    <script>
    fetch("url").then(
        res => {
          res.json().then(
            data => {
            //   console.log(data.Algo);
              if (data.Algo.length > 0) {
      
                var temp = "";
                data.Algo.forEach((itemData) => {
                  temp += "<tr>";
                  temp += "<td>" + itemData.oi + "</td>";
                  temp += "<td>" + itemData.oichange + "</td>";
                  temp += "<td>" + itemData.vol + "</td>";
                  temp += "<td>" + itemData.changeltp + "</td>";
                  temp += "<td>" + itemData.ltp + "</td>";
                  temp += "<td>" + itemData.strike + "</td>";
                  temp += "<td>" + itemData.ltp2 + "</td>";
                  temp += "<td>" + itemData.changeltp2 + "</td>";
                  temp += "<td>" + itemData.vol2 + "</td>";
                  temp += "<td>" + itemData.oichange2 + "</td>";
                  temp += "<td>" + itemData.oi2 + "</td></tr>";
                });
                document.getElementById('datapcr').innerHTML = temp;
              }
            }
          )
        }
      )</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of the response from the API, that's completely dependant on if you can provide a filter in your API request however if you simply want to filter the response, you can add an **if statement** to your code where you are looping through the API response data.

```
data.Algo.forEach((itemData) => {
    if (itemData.value > 10) {
        temp += "<tr>";
        temp += "<td>" + itemData.oi + "</td>";
        temp += "<td>" + itemData.oichange + "</td>";
        temp += "<td>" + itemData.vol + "</td>";
        temp += "<td>" + itemData.changeltp + "</td>";
        temp += "<td>" + itemData.ltp + "</td>";
        temp += "<td>" + itemData.strike + "</td>";
        temp += "<td>" + itemData.ltp2 + "</td>";
        temp += "<td>" + itemData.changeltp2 + "</td>";
        temp += "<td>" + itemData.vol2 + "</td>";
        temp += "<td>" + itemData.oichange2 + "</td>";
        temp += "<td>" + itemData.oi2 + "</td></tr>";
    }
});
document.getElementById('datapcr').innerHTML = temp;
```

now the temp HTML string will only add a new row if the current item in the response data has a value greater than 10. Note I have just used `itemData.value` but you will probably want to alter this to whichever value in the data needs to be positive.

Comment: hello can u help me with to color this value with red and green... positive value will be green and negative will red... i've tried css is not working and i'm not able to fit as javascript